# Spring security oauth2 'dependencies.dependency.version' is missing for spring boot 2.0.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3

I try to add dependency of spring security.
This is my pom.xml

```
<properties>        
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
<dependencies>
```

I try with artifactId spring-security-oauth2, it said: 
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar is missing

but with spring 1.4.2.RELEASE, It work.
What is the new spring security oauth2 maven repo for springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE? (without  element)
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Error saying that you haven't defined version for `spring-security-oauth2`

You can use 2.3.3 version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, I updated my question, can I add dependency without <version> element? with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE I do not need to define <version>

Comment: spring-security-oauth2 is not provided by Spring-boot framework. So you have to add version manually

Comment: did you try with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE? The same pom above, just change 2.0.3 to 1.4.2

Comment: spring-security-oauth2 is compile time dependency in 1.4.2 version of spring boot but not in 2.0.3 version. So you have to define the version manually.